# Prevent Link from activating on click on card icon in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling

I have a card wrapped in a `Link` from the `react-router-dom@v5`. Inside the `Link` is a div for the card and the div is positioned relatively. Inside the card div is an icon positioned absolutely to the card that when clicked should change background color. The problem now is that clicking on the icon also clicks the `Link` which I don't want. I tried to use `e.preventDefault()` but it also stops all subsequent events from firing again properly as I want to be able to flip the background color of the icon any time I click on it. I tried `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation` but they don't seem to work.

I have also gone through several SO answers but none seem to fix my problem.

```
 function handleFavClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(event);
 }

 <Link to={`/movies/${movie.id}`} key={movie.id}>

      <div 
        className="card"
        key={movie.id}
      >
        <img 
          src="/heart-icon.png"
          alt="heart icon"
          onClick={handleFavClick}
        />
        <img 
          src="/card-image.png"
          alt="original card image"

        />
      </div>  
 </Link>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: If you simply want the icon to change background color when you click it, why did you put the Link? Some pictures of what this component looks like would help get a better picture of what you are trying to do

Comment: The Link is to point to a details page about the card. I want to change the background color of the icon when I click on it.

Comment: What I initially want to do is create a movie card that contains an image and also a favorite icon positioned absolutely on the card which is the one I have a problem with. When the user clicks on the favorite icon, change its background to indicate that it was saved. Wrapping the card in a `Link` will point to a page containing details about the movie. But I want the user to be able to click on the favorite icon without having to go to the details page first.

Answer (score 0):

`Event.preventDefault()` works when submitting a form in order to prevent the page from reloading.
In other not to click on the link tag from `react-router-dom`, you should remove img tag from the Link tag.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

const onClickFunction = () =>{

const handleFavClick = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault() 
    console.log(event);
 }

return (
  <>
  <Link to={`/movies/${movie.id}`} key={movie.id}>
     <div className="card" key={movie.id}>
     <img src="/card-image.png" alt="original card image"/>
     </div>  
 </Link>
 <img src="/heart-icon.png" alt="heart icon" onClick={handleFavClick}/>
 </>
);
}

export default onClickFunction;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with the `e.preventDefault()` too. It works incorrectly. When I click the icon, it changes, doesn't fire anything else. If I click on it again to flip the background color, it doesn't detect the click until I click on an outer area from the icon.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. Taking the icon out of the card kinda works and stops the  clicking on the card. The icon is brought out of the document as I would like to place the icon on the card as it was in the design.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the `Link` from being triggered when clicking on the heart icon while still allowing the `handleFavClick` function to execute, you can wrap the `Link` with a `div` and place the `onClick` event handler on that `div`. This way, clicking the heart icon won't trigger the `Link`. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
<div onClick={() => handleFavClick(movie.id)}>
  <Link to={`/movies/${movie.id}`} key={movie.id}>
    <div className="card" key={movie.id}>
      <img src="/heart-icon.png" alt="heart icon" />
      <img src="/card-image.png" alt="original card image" />
    </div>
  </Link>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the issue. It was because, in my CSS, I was using an hover and focus style that was still reflecting even after a click to toggle the background color of the favorite icon.